# How to decompose tempered distribution by entire analytic functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\phi$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on $\mathbb R^{n}$ with

$ \operatorname{supp} \phi \subset \{\xi \in \mathbb R^{n}: |\xi|\leq 2, \phi(\xi)=1$ if $|\xi|\leq 1.$

Let $j\in \mathbb N$ and 
$$\phi_{j}(\xi)= \phi(2^{-j}\xi)- \phi(2^{-j+1}\xi),  (\xi \in \mathbb R^{n})$$

Then we have 
$$\operatorname{supp} \phi_{j} \subset \{\xi\in \mathbb R^{n}: 2^{j-1}\leq |\xi| \leq 2^{j+1} \},  j\in \mathbb N $$
and, with $\phi_{0}=\phi,$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k}(\xi)=1, \text{if} \ \xi\in \mathbb R^{n}.$$
In other words, $\{\phi_{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb N_{0}}$ is a resolution of unity. Let $f\in \mathcal{S'}$ then 
$\phi_{k}(D)f(x)= (\phi_{k}\hat{f})^{\vee}(x), k\in \mathbb N_{0}, x \in \mathbb R^{n}$
is an entire analytic function.

> **My Question is**: (1) How to show  $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k}(D)f;$
>   convergence in $\mathcal{S'},$ and $f=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k}(D)f,$ that is, $f$ can be decompose by entire analytic functions.

**Motivation**: The  sequences $(\phi_{k}\hat{f})^{\vee}$ generats [Besove spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space) if it in $L^{p}(\ell^{q}).$

**My attempt**: [A sequence $\{f_{j}\}_{j\in \mathbb N}$ in $\mathcal{S'}$ is said to converge to $f\in \mathcal{S'}$ if $\langle f_{j}, \psi \rangle \to \langle f, \psi\rangle$ for all $\psi \in \mathcal{S}$ as $j\to \infty.$]

Formally, we put $F=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \phi_{k}^{\vee}\ast f.$
I guess, first I should show: $F\in \mathcal{S'}$, that  is, $\langle F, \psi_{1}+\psi_{2}\rangle =\langle F, \psi_{1}\rangle + \langle F, \psi_{2}\rangle$ for $\psi_{1}, \psi_{2} \in \mathcal{S}$ and for any sequence $\{\psi_{j}\}_{j\in \mathbb N}$
in $\mathcal{S}$ that converges in $\mathcal{S}$ to zero, the sequence of numbers $\langle F, \psi_{j}\rangle$ converges to 0.

For any $\psi \in \mathcal{S},$ we note that,
$\langle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\phi_{k}^{\vee}\ast f, \psi \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\langle \phi_{k}^{\vee}\ast f, \psi \rangle$